# Importing Volley to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, http-post, android-volley, http-get

1. Because of my application's high percentage usage of networking,
   Volley would be the best choice for Http get and post operations.
2. That's why I want to import Volley framework in my Android Studio
       1.0.2.

What are the steps that I should follow?,

Comment: What version of Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this one: https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

You just have to put the " compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6@aar' " into the dependencies in your gradle

Answer (score 1):

You can use an official Google build of Volley with the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

This is compiled directly from AOSP source rather than being a fork like the `mcxiaoke` version.